# Startup command won't execute

Tags: display, command-line, startup

I need to run the command at startup to calibrate my screen using Xcaliber

```
xcaliber --bR=256 --bG=256 --bB=212 --gR=1.04 --gG=0.9600000000000001 --gB=1.01
```

So I tried to set it as a custom startup command, but it won't run at startup, so I have to do it via the terminal.

Moreover, when I press the shift key to delete permanently a file, the screen is turning back to the original configuration, so I have to run back the command again..

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create a script and add it as a custom startup command.

`~/.local/bin/start_xcaliber.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
xcaliber --bR=256 --bG=256 --bB=212 --gR=1.04 --gG=0.9600000000000001 --gB=1.01
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit to lemonslice's recommendation, I would create a .desktop file linking to the script. Then add it to your startup via the System Settings. It works perfectly for me. Here is an example of what I've done...

create a new text file and add the following:

```
#!/bin/bash/

xcaliber --bR=256 --bG=256 --bB=212 --gR=1.04 --gG=0.9600000000000001 --gB=1.01
```

Save as display.sh or something like that.

Then in the terminal navigate to the folder where your display.sh is saved and run the below command in the terminal:

```
chmod +x display.sh
```

This will set the script as executable.

Now you need to create a desktop file so we can add the script to your startup. Open a new text file and name it something like xcaliber.desktop.

add the following to the file:

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Type=Application 
Encoding=UTF-8 
Name=Display Setter Application 
Comment=A script to set xcaliber settings 
Exec=/path/to/display.sh //obviously here you want to add the true path to your file 
Icon=/path/to/icon.png //and here you want to add the true path to your icon file if you want one different from the base gear 
Terminal=false
```

Once that is done open System Settings > Applications > Startup (I think that's what it's called) and add your xcaliber setter application.